# how to increase progress bar on finger touch motion in android?

Tags: android

I have implemented a code which display back image on touch . Where touch finger move that area of back image view display and front image view become invisible . I just want scrub massage on hand my code is here can anybody suggest how i do that ..

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new TouchView(this));

}

class TouchView extends View {
    Bitmap bgr;
    Bitmap overlayDefault;
    Bitmap overlay;
    Paint pTouch;
    int X = -100;
    int Y = -100;
    Canvas c2;

    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bgr);
        overlayDefault = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.over);
        overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.over).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        c2 = new Canvas(overlay);

        pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT));
        pTouch.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        pTouch.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.NORMAL));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        switch (ev.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            X = (int) ev.getX();
            Y = (int) ev.getY();
            invalidate();

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            X = (int) ev.getX();
            Y = (int) ev.getY();
            invalidate();
            break;

        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // draw background
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);
        // copy the default overlay into temporary overlay and punch a hole
        // in it
        c2.drawBitmap(overlayDefault, 0, 0, null); // exclude this line to
                                                    // show all as you draw
        c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 80, pTouch);
        // draw the overlay over the background
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, null);

    }

}}
```

please help for it ....

Comment: what u want can u show some snap its not clear?

Comment: I want draw effect on my image like cream color on touch, where my finger move that color display on image. And increase state of progress bar on finger movement. do you have idea how i do that ?

Comment: how to do that anybody can suggest please ?